# Can't reach the /21 VLSM IP address given to me by my ISP from the internet

Tags: linux, networking

I'm having trouble reaching my home IP address from the internet. The ISP gave me an address with a variable length subnet mask. 97.97.200.XXX/21 to get exact without giving it all away.  My question is how can I reach it with SSH or anything useful for backing up files? Ping and traceroute give me results for the class A address as they seem to have no options for specifying subnet masks. Is there some other protocol that would allow me to reach this IP from the internet?

Comment: First check your home IP http://cqcounter.com/whois/ then ping it. And tell us your topology - how your devices are connected.

Answer (score 1):

First, CIDR is a more relevant term here, and to be clear, it's not a "CIDR IP address". CIDR is merely a notation method. Additionally, don't mention classful addressing if you want to be taken seriously. :)

Second, the protocol used to communicate from one IP to another is, you guessed it, IP. If you are unable to do this, there's either a routing issue or firewall issue, or both.

Since this is a home internet circuit, it's likely that inbound connections are being restricted by your ISP or you don't have your router configured to properly handle inbound requests.